# Filtering out mailing lists on the server

Tags: mail.app, email

Apple Mail is good at filtering mailing-list email into my junk folder, and my iPhone is good at recognizing email from a list.  I'd like to move this capability to some server-side filter rules and unburden my phone. Unfortunately I don't know what it is that Apple Mail looks at to make its decision.

Can somebody please explain, in simple terms, what to look for?  I've tried 'from address contains' and 'subject contains' and 'mailing list contains' without much luck. Truthfully, I'm not sure what to put in 'mailing list contains' except that my email address isn't it. I am aware that I'll have to accept the lists I want before purging the ones I don't.

Looking for any help or advice on getting this set up.  My email server is Cox.

Answer (score 1):

To implement server side rules, your *server* must support it.

There’s nothing in Apple Mail that can enable something on the server if the server doesn’t support that feature.

I searched Cox’s Support site for “server side rules” and found nothing.  Additionally, I found [this message](https://www.cox.com/residential/support/cox-email-server-settings.html)

> Cox Email is a free service that was included with all Cox High Speed Internet packages. As of August 15, 2019, Cox Email is no longer available to new users.

This pretty much means that while the service isn’t discontinued yet, there’s no further development.  So, if you’d like server side rules, you will need to find another provider.  I personally like [Outlook.com](https://outlook.live.com) as you get the Exchange like server features along with a OneDrive account and free online versions Office.

Comment: I'm not asking Apple to do it, I'm asking how Apple does it, so I can attempt to do it. In this link, about halfway down, are the Cox filter options: https://www.cox.com/residential/support/cox-email-settings.html. Gmail can filter on list-id.  Not all spam has a list id, so what does Apple use? I presume it's in the header. I'd say thanks, but that's deprecated around here.

Comment: Ahhh..  I believe it’s [Spam Assassin](https://opensource.apple.com/source/SpamAssassin/SpamAssassin-124/) because it’s listed in their open source repository. Lots of clients use it from Outlook and  Exchange to stand-alone implementations.  It’s not a list of filters or rules, but an “engine” that detects spam

Comment: Not sure what to say, literally. But I will note that Spam Assassin has a folder of rules and that Cox email supports some version of Regex, so I'd think I can take it from here. Than..